# Updating a specific field in a table via form

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to update a Model via a table front end in django - no matter what I've tried I can't get this to work with my class based view.

Image of the website.
[image]

from what I understand, the `forms.py` is trying to insert a new record `INSERT VALUES(id, null, null, null ,1)` from the example.

I've toyed with only using the `field` that I'm interested in, but it still attempts to create a new record in my table.

where as I want to update the record in the dataset, i.e

```sql
update public.product_table
set price_checked = 1
where product_id = ...
```

sorry for the amount of code!

#### `models.py`

```
from django.db import models
class ProductTable(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
        editable=False
    )

    product_name = models.TextField(max_length=255,null=False)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6,decimal_places=2,null=False)
    from_date = models.DateTimeField()
    to_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    price_checked = models.IntegerField(default=0,null=False)

    def __str__(self : str) -> str:
        return f"{self.product_name}"
```

#### `forms.py`

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import ProductTable


class ProductUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductTable
        fields = '__all__'
```

#### `views.py`

```
from typing import Any, Dict

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .forms import ProductUpdateForm
from .models import ProductTable


class TableDataView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = ProductTable
    context_object_name = 'product'
    template_name = 'tables/product.html'


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs: Any) -> Dict[str, Any]:
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['product'] = ProductTable.objects.all()[:5]

        return context


    def post(self,request):
        if request.method=='POST':
            form  = ProductUpdateForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success('price checked..')
            return redirect('product')
```

#### `product.html`

```html
    <form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|crispy }}
      <div class="container mx-flex pt-5 mb-5">
        <h1 class="text-center pb-2">Eurocarparts Products</h1>
        <div class="row" id="loading">
          <table
            id="product-table"
            class="table table-striped table-bordered"
            style="width: 100%; display: none"
          >
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Product</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Date Added</th>
                <th>Date Removed</th>
                <th>Price Checked?</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {% for data in product %}
              <tr>
                <th>{{ data.product_name }}</th>
                <th>{{ data.price }}</th>
                <th>{{ data.from_date }}</th>
                <th>{{ data.to_date }}</th>
                <th>
                  <label for="price-check">
                    <input
                      class="form"
                      name="price_checked"
                      type="number"
                    />
                  </label>
                </th>
              </tr>
              {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" id="product-table">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in order to update an object using a ModelForm you must pass it an instance parameter:

```
def post(self,request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        product_table = ProductTable.objects.get(id=<some_id>)
        form  = ProductUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=product_table)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success('price checked..')
        return redirect('product')
```

You can send your id using a `HiddenInput` with the id value placed in the same form.

Second, you're trying to update 5 fields at once. You must either update them one at a time, or use a FormSets.

Edit (hidden input):

```
  <tr>
    <th>{{ data.product_name }}</th>
    <th>{{ data.price }}</th>
    <th>{{ data.from_date }}</th>
    <th>{{ data.to_date }}</th>
    <th>
      <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="{{data.id}}">
      <label for="price-check">
        <input
          class="form"
          name="price_checked"
          type="number"
        />
      </label>
    </th>
  </tr>
```

Then in the view:

```
product_table = ProductTable.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('product_id'))
```

Comment: awesome! thank you for the clear guidance, can you tell me about formsets? or point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/formsets/  . This is normally where the docs should be but right now I get an SSL error. Maybe you won't, but if it doesn't work search on youtube about django formsets.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! can you show an example of the `hidden input` if it exceeds the scope of this question then I totally understand.